# Find the next occurrence of a variable in vim

Tags: search, vim, variables

I would like to know if/how I can make vim look for the next occurrence of a variable. Let's say the variable's name is simply 'n', then `/n` would give me all occurrences of that letter, which isn't always terribly helpful. I guess I could create a regex to solve the problem, but I wondered whether there was some command/keystroke I simply don't yet know about; and as all my googling has been to no avail I decided to put a question on here.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: are you looking for something that is syntax aware and makes the distinction between the simple letter n inside a word and a variable whose name is n ?

Comment: @kriss This is exactly what I'm looking for, yes. But if I can get the variable/name finding functionality in the absence of syntax awareness I'd be satisfied as well.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you have the cursor over the variable in question, you can press `*` and it will search for the next occurrence or `#` will search for the previous one.

This is equivalent to typing:

```
/\<n\>
```

(`\<` matches on the start of a word and `\>` matches on the end of word).  The only difference (for reasons I'm not sure of) is that `*` and `#` don't pay attention to the `'smartcase'` option.

See:

```
:help *
:help /\<
```

Comment: @Al I was not aware of * and # paying attention to word boundaries, so thanks a lot for pointing it out to me!

Comment: Also have a look at `:help pattern`

Comment: It's a good feature certainly. But unfortunately it's not just variables since it can also be in strings. For example if you have `char str[]="test"; int s = 5; printf("%s\n", str);` then the 's' in the format specifier will also be matched. I could swear that there is a way without any external tools but I cannot for the life of me remember what it is or if I am mixing it up with something else but it's a good reminder about word boundaries.

Answer (score 56):

If you press `n` in command mode it will give you the next match of your search.

More detail:

- `/` will start forward search
- `?` will start backward search
- `n` will give you the next result *in the direction you are searching*
- `N` will give you the previous result *wrt the direction you are searching in*

Comment: shouldn't it be `N` ? `n` is for the previous match.

Comment: Not if caps-lock is on! >.>

Comment: You have to search for that string before pressing `n` for next occurence though? `*` or `#` goes to the next occurence of the word under the cursor.

Comment: as much as I like `n` it does not search for the next occurrence of the word under the cursor. use `*`.

Comment: @HarryMoreno But once you have hit `*` then `n` *does* search for the next one.

Comment: @ChungLunYuen Yes that's right. Maybe you weren't asking that as a question literally though?

Comment: @ChrisMaes No. You're mixed up. `N` is for previous; `n` is for next. **Unless** your initial search you went backwards. This is the same for pagers that have the `n`/`N` functionality.

Comment: @Pryftan: 1. this is not my answer, I just edited it. 2. this answer is correct, though it might be more complete (I tried to complete it more).

Comment: @ChrisMaes (1) I never suggested it was :) (2) You wanted to make it more complete? I was trying to make your comment more complete. I was pointing out that you were mixed up with the directions - that's all. Nothing other than that. If it came across as belittling you I don't know why but I'm sorry if it did cause any discontent. The best I can think of is that maybe the bold in my comment made you think there was more to it but I assure you there was not. Anyway as I noted `N` is for the previous and `n` is for the next (hence you mixing it up). Cheers.

Comment: @pryftan my apologies, I hadn't seen my old comment.