# Vim: find in next line

Tags: vim

In vim I can use `f+Character` to find the next character on this line. But when I already found the last character, it won't take me to the next character on the next line.

```
int x = md(v.x + perm(y)); //cursor at last )
float permut = perm(x);
```

When I type `f+(` it won't take me to the `(` on the next line.
Why? Can I change this behavior?

Comment: You can press n when you have already searched.

Comment: `f` is a linewise motion. It only operates on the line your cursor is positioned on. You want `/` to search through all lines in a buffer. The equivalent of your `f(` to search and `;` for the next match would be `/(/g` to search and `n` for the next match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the next occurrence of a variable in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408719/find-the-next-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `/(` instead to search multiple lines, followed by `n` for next match

Answer (score 2):

Press `j0f)` to find first `(` in next line.

```
   j - move line down
   0 - move to first character
   f) - find `(`
```